# Handling Http Request with Apache2 (or Nginx). Does a new process gets created for each or a set of N requests?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, nginx, httpserver

Will a web server (WS) (like apache2 or nginix (or container like tomcat(TC)) create a new process to handle incoming request. My concern is about servers that support high number of parallel users (say 20K+ parallel users).
I think load balancing happens on the other side of web server (if it is used to front Tomcat etc). So in theory, a single web server should be accepting all the (20K+)incoming request before it can distribute the load to other servers backing it.
**So, the questions is: Does Web Server (WS) handle all these requests in a single process or it smartly spawns other process to help share the work (i know the "client - server" binding happens though** - ***client_host:random_port***  plus ***server_host:fixed_port***).

**Reference:** Prior to reading this article:[Fronting Tomcat with Apache](http://people.apache.org/~mturk/docs/article/ftwai.html) I was thinking it is a single process doing all the smart work. But in this article there is mentioning of MPM (Multi-Processing Module)

> It combines the best from two worlds, having a set of child processes each having a set of separate threads. There are sites that are running 10K+ concurrent connections using this technology.

And as it goes, it is getting more sophisticated as threads also being spawned like mentioned above. (these are not the tomcat threads that serve each individual request by calling the service method, but these are threads on Apache WS to handle request and distribute them to nodes for processing).
If any one used MPM. Little further explanation of how all this works will be great.
Questions like -
(1) As child processes are spawned what is it exact role. Is the child process just for mediating the request to tomcat or any thing more. If so, then after the child process gets response from TC, does the child process forward the response to parent process or directly to the client (since it can know the ***client_host:random_port*** from parent process. I am not sure if this is allowed in theory, though the child process can not accept any new request as the ***fixed_port*** which can bind to only one process is already tied to parent process.
(2) What kind of load is shared to thread by the child or parent process. Again it must almost be same as in (1). But what I am not sure is that even in theory if a thread can directly send the request to client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache historically use prefork model of processing. In this model each request == separate operation system (OS) process. It's calling "prefork" because Apache fork some spare processes and process request within. If number of preforked processes not enough - Apache fork new. Pros: process can execute other modules or processes and not care that they do; cons: each request = one process, too much memory used and OS fork also can be slow for your requests.

Other model of Apache - worker MPM. Almost same as prefork, but using not OS processes but OS threads. Thread - it's like lightweight process. One OS process can run many threads using one memory space. Worker MPM used much less memory and new threads created fast. Cons: modules need to support thread, crash of module can crash all threads of all OS process (but this it not important for you because you are using apache as reverse proxy only). Other cons: CPU [switching context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) when switching between threads.

So yes, worker much better than prefork in your case, but...

But we have Nginx :) Nginx using other model (btw, Apache has event MPM too). In this case you has only one process (well, can be few processes, see below). How it works. New request rising special event, OS process waking up, receive request, prepare answer, write answer and gone sleep.

You can say "wow, but this is not multitasking" and will be right. But one big difference between this model and simple sequentially request processing. What happens if you need write big data to slow client? In synchronous way your process need to wait acknowledging about data receiving and only after - process new request. Nginx and Apache event model use asynchronous model. Nginx tell to OS to send some piece of data write this data to OS buffer and... gone sleep, or process new requests. When OS will send piece of data - special event will be sent to nginx. So, main difference - Nginx do not wait I/O (like connect, read, write), Nginx tell to OS that he want and OS send event to Nginx than this task ready (socket connected, data written or new data ready to read in local buffer). Also, modern OS can work asynchronously with HDD (read/write) and even can send files from HDD to tcp socket directly.

Sure, all math operations in this Nginx process will block this process and its stop to process new and existing requests. But when main workflow is work with network (reverse proxy, forward requests to FastCGI or other backend server) plus send static files (asynchronous too) - Nginx can serve thousands simultaneous requests in one OS process! Also, because one process of OS (and one thread) - CPU will execute it in one context.

How I told before - Nginx can start few OS processes and each of this process will be assigned by OS to separate CPU core. Almost no reasons to fork more Nginx OS processes (there is only one reason to do it: if you need to do some blocking operations, but simple reverse proxy with backend balancing - not this case)

So, pros: less CPU context switching, less memory (comparing with worker MPM too), fast connection processing. More pros: Nginx created as HTTP load balancer and have lot of options for it (and even more in commercial Nginx Plus). Cons: If you need some hard math inside OS process, this process will be blocked (but all you math in Tomcat, so Nginx only balancer).

*PS: typo fix will come later, out of time. Also, my English bad, so fixes always welcome :)*

PPS: Answer question about number of TC thread, asked in comments (was too long for post as comment):

Best way to know it - test it using stress loading tools. Because this number depend on application profile. Response time is not good enough to help answer. Because, for example, big difference between 200ms of 100% math (100% cpu bound) vs 50ms of math + 150ms of sleep waiting database answer.

If application is 100% CPU bound - probably one thread per one core, but in real cases all applications also spent some time in I/O (receive request, send answer to client).

If application work with I/O and need to wait for answers from other services (database, for example), this application spends some time in sleep state and CPU can process other tasks.

So best solution to create number of requests close to real load and run stress test increasing number of concurrent requests (and number of TC workers for sure). Find acceptable response time and fix this number of threads. Sure, need to check before that it is not database fault.

Sure, here I'm talking about dynamic content only, requests for static files from disk must be processed before tomcat (by Nginx, for example).

Comment: great details. Tx. One another important configuration parameter I want to ask - What is a safe value for the number of thread that can be used on each tomcat worker. (Preferably as a function of Number of Processor Cores - *NC* and Number of HT if any per Processor *HTP*). I have NC=4 and HTP=2, so total logical processors available are 8. Then what should be my total number of threads for this worker.  That might be tricky to answer with the little info, but some guidelines will help. Tx

Comment: I answered you question as PPS in answer above, because too much characters for this comment.

Comment: this is what answers my query - "If application is 100% CPU bound - probably one thread per one core" . Excellent. Rest, I can benchmark for non-cpu intensive applications through CPU (System and User) usage vs idle time etc.  Thanks.